Firebase legacy FCM API to Http v1 migration fails due to json request
In our team, we use the legacy Firebase FCM API, and we need to migrate to new HTTP v1 API. Our code base in c#.
I checked the official document(https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1), however, after making the changes according to the document, we get 400 bad request error. What we have done so far:

Used new authorization interface to obtain token bearer( we can confirm we get the bearer)

Use this token bearer in our http request's authorization part.


Our old json request:
{
  "to": "xxxx",
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true,
  "data": {
    "pushType": "troyHCE",
    "digitizedCardId": "",
    "Header": "TROYHCE",
    "Type": "REQUEST_SESSION",
    "Message": "{'sessionID':’xxxxxxx’ }",
    "android": {
      "priority": "high"
    },
    "webpush": {
      "headers ": {
        "Urgency": "high"
      }
    }
  }
} 
new request we try to send after checking the document
{
  "message": {
    "token": "xxxx",
    "priority": "high",
    "content_available": true,
    "data": {
      "pushType": "troyHCE",
      "digitizedCardId": "",
      "Header": "TROYHCE",
      "Type": "REQUEST_SESSION",
      "Message": "{'sessionID':’xxxxxxx’ }",
      "android": {
        "priority": "high"
      },
      "webpush": {
        "headers ": {
          "Urgency": "high"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
this request gives us directly a 400 bad request. However when we try as an example
{
  "message": {
    "token": "xxxx",
    "notification": {
      "body": "This is an FCM notification message!",
      "title": "FCM Message"
    }
  }
}
this works as expected.That means our token bearer etc works.However 'data' part we get from our supplier service, gives the the request in the form of first json request I shared. Therefore, we are having problem to adjust to new api interating the data part. What should we change?

If you using admin sdk then you can directly pass it like this.
  {
    token: token,
    data: {
      "pushType": "troyHCE",
      "digitizedCardId": "",
      "Header": "TROYHCE",
      "Type": "REQUEST_SESSION",
      "Message": "{sessionID:'xxxxxxx' }",
    },
    android: {
      "priority": "high"
    },
    webpush: {
      "headers": {
        "Urgency": "high"
      }
    }
  }

If you are using rest api to send notification add this whole as value for new key "message"
{
    message: JSON 
}

